# MySQL getting customer's name from order ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join

If  have two tables and I need customer's name from order ID.

Customer:

```
ID     Name
1      Jamal Wang
2      Omar Jan
```

Orders:

```
╔═══════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║  ID   ║ CUSTOMER ║ VALUE ║
╠═══════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 34656 ║        1 ║    20 ║
║ 37345 ║        2 ║    25 ║
║ 38220 ║        1 ║    15 ║
║ 39496 ║        1 ║    38 ║
║ 41752 ║        1 ║     9 ║
║ 43734 ║        2 ║    20 ║
```

I would like to get customer name when I have customer ID from 'Orders'

```
SELECT Name FROM `Customer` 
INNER JOIN `Order`
ON Customer.id = Order.customer.
WHERE Customer.id=1
```

But it returns the same customer 4 times as I have 4 Orders. 
How can I make it not return customber based on "Orders" but based on "Customer".
I need customer's name from order ID.
Please help.

Comment: Just twice? That should come back 4 times.

Comment: why do you join with 'Orders' when you have customer id and you need customer name. You don't need anything from orders table.

Comment: you should modify the filter: `SELECT * FROM  Customer
INNER JOIN Order
ON Customer.ID= Order.CUSTOMER
WHERE Order.ID=37345` this gives you one row

Comment: ofcourse its giving 4 times because customer #1 has 4 orders.

Comment: If you want it to show only one time use { select distinct }

Comment: Why are you selecting from the ORDER table at all?

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to join with 'Order' table if you already had the customer ID. Just use simple select:

```
SELECT Name FROM `Customer` 
WHERE ID=1
```

You should only use join if you want to get customer name based on order ID.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned already, in this particular query you don't need the order table at all.

However, if you wanted to keep your existing query and only get the name *once* (which is your question) then just add the `DISTINCT` keyword to your existing query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM customer
INNER JOIN order ON customer.id = order.customer
WHERE customer.id = 1;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/398ed2/2) example.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this? I gave a working answer to the question they asked.